# How to build tetra-quark mesons symmetry group?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, group-representations, quarks, mesons

I was thinking about the issue while reviewing my group theory notes. One can construct mesons with a nonet as an octet and a singlet, $SU(3)\otimes SU(3) = 8\oplus \bar{1}$. In a same way but for $qq$ interactions it is $6\oplus \bar{3}$. How about i.e, $(ud\bar{u}\bar{d})$ bound state or i.e, $(ud\bar{s}\bar{d})$ ?

So, suppose the meson is bounded as diquark-diantiquark pair. Then I guess sextet and triplet may remain to refer $qq$ diquark and then I try to figure out the di-antiquark part, I think that part should be a singlet but actually not quite sure.

Anyway, these are just a naive assumptions of mine. I'd be appreciated if someone help me to figure out the -thfold Way to exotic multi-quarks.

Comment: Don't you just take the $\mathbf{3}\otimes\mathbf{3}\otimes\bar{\mathbf{3}}\otimes\bar{\mathbf{3}}$ and decompose it to get what the $ud\bar u\bar d$ might be?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think so but I can not figure out the multiplets of $(6\oplus \bar{3})\otimes \bar{3}\otimes \bar{3}$

Comment: It might be tedious, but that's just drawing the Young diagrams correctly.

Comment: @ACuriousMind yeah, that's the point I got lost.

Answer (score 1):

Your $SU(3)\otimes SU(3)={\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 8}$ above is a chimaeric typo from hell.

OK, I'll just give you the self-evident answers, but they would be meaningless junk numbers if you failed to reproduce them directly on the basis of your SU(3) text or the [WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Clebsch.E2.80.93Gordan_series_from_the_tableaux) which explains the rules and the Dynkin representation notation, *D(p,q)*, which connects to the Young tableaux directly, but which I will nevertheless not use. I'll just use the dimensionality of the rep as its sole label, $D(1,0)={\bf 3}, ~D(2,0)={\bf 6},~ D(3,0)={\bf 10},~ D(1,1)={\bf 8}, ~D(2,2)={\bf 27}$, etc, and the numbers in parenthesis before each to denote the multiplicity of such multiplets in the C-G reduction.

So these are the answers you should be able to work out in less than an hour:
$${\bf 3}\otimes {\bf 3}\otimes {\bf \bar{3}}\otimes {\bf \bar{3}} = ( {\bf 6}\oplus {\bf \bar{3}})\otimes ({\bf 3}\oplus {\bf \bar{6}})= ({\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 8})  \otimes ({\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 8}) ~. $$
So you have two options/pathways to get to your answers, and it is highly recommended you do both, for consistency.

Firstly, work out $({\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 8}) \otimes ({\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 8})= {\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 8}  \oplus {\bf 8} \oplus ({\bf 8} \otimes {\bf 8})$ and 
${\bf 8} \otimes {\bf 8}={\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 8} \oplus {\bf 8}  \oplus {\bf 10} \oplus {\bf \overline{10} }  \oplus {\bf 27},$ and check the arithmetic of the dimensionalities, so you have not left anything out.

Alternatively, work out, perhaps more simply, $   {\bf 6}  \otimes  {\bf 3}= {\bf 8}\oplus {\bf 10}$, its obvious conjugate, ${\bf \bar{3}}\otimes  {\bf 3}=   {\bf  1}  \oplus {\bf  8}$, and $ {\bf 6}\otimes {\bf \bar{6}}=
 {\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 27} \oplus {\bf  8}$.

So, distributing terms in the above, the final answer is 
$$
{\bf 3}\otimes {\bf 3}\otimes {\bf \bar{3}}\otimes {\bf \bar{3}} = 
(2) {\bf 1} \oplus (4) {\bf  8} \oplus {\bf 10} \oplus {\bf \overline{10}}
 \oplus {\bf 27} ~.
$$
Check conservation of states, as always--elt. school arithmetic.

Note the allowed isospins are then *I*=0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2, and the hyper charges, *Y*= 0, $\pm 1, ~\pm 2$, The last two hypercharches, $\pm 2$, are exotic for plain $\bar{q}q $ mesons, and so are *I*= 3/2, 2 !!!

Further note over 3/4 of all states are in self-conjugate representations.